# Create a table in database

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

i am trying to create a new table in my asp application and for the love of me cannot work out how to use the primary key syntax. I am trying to work out how to create it in the first place.
could someone show me whats wrong with the query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserTestScores]
(  
  [UserName]            NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
  [MomentsAndEnergyTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
  [MotionInACircleTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
  [UniversalGravtationTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL, 
  [CapacitanceTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL, 
  [ElectricFieldsTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL, 
  [MagneticFieldsTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL, 
  [ElectronsAndNucleiTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
  [ParticlePhysicsTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
  [NuclearDecayTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL, 
  [GasLawsAndKineticTheoryTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL, 
  [InternalEnergyAbsoluteZeroAndChangeOfStateTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
  [SpecificHeatCapacityTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
  [AstrophysicsTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
  [CosmologyTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
  [OscillationsTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY [UserName],
  )


WITH  
(  
    LOCATION = '/folder/file',  
    DATA_SOURCE = [DataSource1],  
    FILE_FORMAT = [FileFormat1] 
)
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't figure out what your question really is.

Comment: The query doesnt work and i dont know why, the error is surrounding the Primary key, id also like to know what the `WITH  
(  
    LOCATION = '/folder/file',  
    DATA_SOURCE = [DataSource1],  
    FILE_FORMAT = [FileFormat1] 
) `

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit speculative because the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql#syntax) does not seem to be complete.  In particular, it does not define the syntax for `column_definition` as it applies to `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`.

Notably absent from the syntax diagram is anything about constraints.  Comparison to the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql#syntax) for `CREATE TABLE` can be instructive -- no computed columns, no explicit constraints, no column sets, no partitions for the external version.

The documentation is explicit that `DEFAULT` is not allowed.  I suspect no constraints are allowed, and that is why you are getting a syntax error.  I would be surprised if an in-line constraint were allowed when an explicit constraint does not appear to be part of the syntax.

However, `column_definition` would appear to allow the inline `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, which is why I think the documentation is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that you haven't named the primary key.  You have indicated which field the primary key is based on (`UserName`) but you haven't named the actual primary key.  So I'm not sure of the syntax, but I would think you need to change the line to something like this:

pk_UserName PRIMARY KEY [UserName]

You probably also don't need the comma at the end of the line.